# Self-invoking JavaScript (brackets)

Tags: javascript

There is a piece of code :

```
(function aaa(){alert("555")})()
```

and this :

```
(function aaa(){alert("555")}())
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Style. They're functionally identical.

Comment: They both function identically but I believe Douglas Crockford recommends the second though I don't remember why. Give me a sec and I'll see if I can find the article with his recommendation...

Comment: See this answer for more info on IIFE's http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/3561995

Comment: Lol, I can't remember the last time Crockford's opinion was relevant.

Comment: @War10ck Because he thinks the first one [looks like "dog balls"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=taaEzHI9xyY#t=2020s).

Comment: @MikeC Lol, I forgot about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23925102/616443

Answer (score 0):

If you put the first one together twice, it only runs the first one before producing a `TypeError`:

```js
(function aaa(){alert("555")})()(function aaa(){alert("555")})()
```

If you put the second one together twice, it runs both of them before producing a `TypeError`:

```js
(function aaa(){alert("555")}())(function aaa(){alert("555")}())
```

In short, they're two different style choices for scoping code to avoid cluttering the global namespace, but the second one in my experience tends to be favored more since it's less prone to erroring when multiple scopes are concatenated together. It's best to always begin the scope with a semicolon to ensure that it executes when concatenated like so:

```js
;(function aaa(){alert("555")}());(function aaa(){alert("555")}())
```

Comment: Correction: type errors, not syntax errors. They're type errors because you're attempting to call something that isn't a function as a function.

Comment: You're right. I said syntax error, I was thinking logic error in my head. Thank you for the correction.